# NodaTime - can I change default xml serialization for Instant?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, nodatime

NodaTime - can I change default xml serialization for Instant?

Is there a way to change it so all instants would be serialized without milliseconds:

Instead of this:

```
<CreationDateTime>2021-06-27T09:52:18.1900643Z</CreationDateTime>
```

I'd want this:

```
<CreationDateTime>2021-06-27T09:52:18Z</CreationDateTime>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do that for all NodaTime.Instant properties, e.g. with some settings on the XmlSerializer we create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not: the format is hard-coded, effectively. I would suggest either post-processing the XML, or potentially serializing using a separate string property which is purely for the sake of XML (so you'd mark it as obsolete, but serialize it in the way that you want, and it would proxy to an `Instant` property which is *not* obsolete but *is* ignored for XML serialization).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  I think I can probably go through all descendant xelements and use regex.